# Jetty GzipHandler Configuration

Tags: jetty, jetty-9

I am configuring Jetty server to `gzip` the response for my  web-application via `jetty.xml`. Here's the configuration that I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/web</Set>
  <Set name="war">/opt/jetty/webapps/web/web.war</Set>
    <Set name="gzipHandler"> 
        <New id="GzipHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler">

          <Set name="includedMimeTypes">
            <Array type="java.lang.String">
                <Item>application/json</Item>
                <Item>text/html</Item>
                <Item>text/plain</Item>
                <Item>text/xml</Item>
                <Item>application/xhtml+xml</Item>
                <Item>text/css</Item>
                <Item>application/javascript</Item>
                <Item>image/svg+xml</Item>
            </Array>
          </Set>
          <Set name="minGzipSize">1</Set>
          <Set name="includedMethods">
            <Array type="java.lang.String">
                <Item>GET</Item>
                <Item>POST</Item>
            </Array>
          </Set>
          <Set name="includedPaths">
            <Array type="java.lang.String">
                <Item>/*</Item>
            </Array>
          </Set>
          <Set name="excludedPaths">
            <Array type="java.lang.String">
                <Item>/static/*</Item>
            </Array>
          </Set>
        </New>
    </Set>
</Configure>
```

Naturally I would expect all of the listed MIME types to be gzipped. However, when I look at the browser console, I see that the only responses being gzipp'ed are those that have type `image/svg+xml`.
[image]
For instance, `text/html` is not gzipped

[image]

More so, some types ( like `woff2`) which I didn't mention in the `includedMimeTypes` are gzipped.

Is there way to fix/debug this issue ?

Comment: Are you just wanting static resources gzipped? and/or some dynamically generated responses too?

Comment: would be nice to have both, I suppose. As for `/static/*` being excluded that's just images, so they shouldn't be gzipped.